# Chrome treating an element's CSS differently when it's prepended via jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am using Twitter Bootstrap's CSS framework. On top of every page, I have an action bar with some buttons that perform certain common tasks, some of which are normal `inline-block` buttons that get horizontally stacked from the left, and others get the `pull-right` class because they are supposed to be on the right side.

When I do this kind of solution statically, then everything is fine, as showcased in my first Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2mj58m86/. The buttons with no float are on the left side, and the buttons with `.pull-left` are on the right side.

But when I dynamically prepend the "left" button with jQuery, then only in Chrome and Chromium, the new button will push the right button down. They behave as if they are both `block` elements with `text-align` `left` and `right` respectively. This behavior is showcased in the second Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2mj58m86/1/

This is the first time I have personally encountered a situation where a browser treats CSS differently when an element is dynamically added. Is this a Webkit bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Note that this does not happen in Firefox.

Comment: If you remove the "clearfix" class it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `.btn-info` in the CSS to `float: left`, another way you can use `.pull-left`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `append` instead on `prepend`.

```
$('.well').append('<span class="btn btn-info">button one</span>');
```

This would make it work fine. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2mj58m86/4/

Answer (score 0):

Use the bootstrap grid system.

```
<div class="clearfix well">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <span class="btn btn-info pull-right">button two</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$('.well').prepend('<div class="col-sm-6"><span class="btn btn-info pull-left">button one</span></div>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2mj58m86/2/